# How Can I Generalize this Macro I use to Specify Vector Length?

Tags: c

I have two codes: `vector_add.c` and `vector_print.c`. Both require me to assign the vector length *N*, as a macro using `#define N (3)`, where 3 is the length. I am okay with this for `vector_add.c`, but I wan't to generalize `vector_print.c` to work for any vector length, and then just assign the vector length later in another code. I tried using `#undef N` in different ways but I couldn't get it to work.

Does anyone have any suggestion for how I can generalize my `vector_print` function to work for any vector length, *N*? Right now, I'm simply using `#define N (3)` for both files, which works fine for a vector of length 3. But I don't want to explicitly assign a vector length in `vector_print.c`. I want it to work for any *N*!

This is `vector_add.c`:

```
#include <vector_print.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// vector length (fixed)

#define N (3)

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// vector_add
//
// returns the linear sum of the two vectors and puts them in another
// x: first vector
// y: second vector
// z: solution vector

void
vector_add(double *x, double *y, double *z)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    z[i] += x[i] + y[i];
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// main
//
// test the vector_add() function

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  double x[N] = { 1., 2., 3. };
  double y[N] = { 2., 3., 4. };
  double z[N] = {0.,0.,0.};
  vector_add(x, y, z);

  printf("x is ");
  vector_print(x);
  printf("y is ");
  vector_print(y);
  printf("z is ");
  vector_print(z);

  return 0;
}
```

This is is `vector_print.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// vector length (fixed)

#define N (3)

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// vector_print
//
// prints the elements of an N-element array
// name: name of vector to print

void
vector_print(double *name)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%g ", name[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

And if necessary, here is `vector_print.h`:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_PRINT_H
#define VECTOR_PRINT_H

void vector_print(double *name);

#endif
```

Comment: Pass the length as an argument.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar You can pass the length in both functions if you want, or just `vector_print()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just relaying the solution in the comments.

What you can do is pass the length to those functions like this:

```
void vector_print(double *name, int len);
void vector_add(double *x, double *y, double *z, int len);
```

This will allow you to control the loop like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { // Note: i < len now, not N
    printf("%g ", name[i]);
  }
```